# Como capturar el error de Primary Key Duplicated en Android ( java) con SQLServer?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, try-catch

Es posible saber que el error que se produce al insertar un registro es por un error de llave duplicada? 
tengo un registro de usuarios en el cual el usuario es la llave primaria y lo tengo en un `try catch`
pero cuando el usuario ya existe salta al `catch` Ahora lo que quiero es decirle al usuario que no se pudo completar el resgistro porque el usuario ya existe, podría antes de hacer el insert verificar si el usuario existe pero me pregunto si el `catch` podría hacer esa función
aqui el codigo de ejemplo:

```
try{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios values('usuario','password')";
        st.execute(sql);
        connect.close();
}catch(Exception e){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

En el Toast quisiera decirle al usuario que hubo un error de duplicidad, pero el Exception puede saltar por  varias situaciones.

Answer (score 1):

En Java y por ende en Android tienes la excepción `SQLException`, que captura todas las excepciones relacionadas con las sentencias SQL, bien sea un fallo de que no encuentra la tabla, hasta que el campo ya existe y controlaria tu error. Para ejecutar algún código basta simplemente con ponerlo en el bloque del catch.

```
try{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios values('usuario','password')";
        st.execute(sql);
        connect.close();
}catch(SQLException e){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//Intentar la conexión o insertar otro dato
}
```

Comment: `}catch(Exception  | SQLException e){` aunque lo ideal es hacer una consulta si existe

Comment: @JackNavaRow Desde luego, pero el preguntaba por la excpeción exacta para controlar las sentencias. También sería mas recomendable si hace varios catch para ejecutar una acción en cada excepción.

Comment: venga es un ejemplo,explicaria porque "fallo" el Exception en su try/catch